# Getting bounded rect for contours in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I am trying to convert python code to C++ and i am getting issues in below function
which gets the rotation rectangle for contours:
'''

```
def find_rot_rectangle_for_contour(contours):
    # Find the rotated rectangles and ellipses for each contour
    minRect = [None] * len(contours)  # Initializing minRect
    print('length of contour = ',len(contours))
    count = None  #count = 0
    minLength = None # minLength = 0
    tmpLength = 0 #tempLength = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(contours): #index,c= contour
        minRect[i] = cv.minAreaRect(c)  # minRect is ((x,y), (w,h), angle), index(0, 1, 2)
        minLength = min(minRect[i][1])
        print('Minimum Length is',minLength)
        if ((minLength > 500) and (minLength > tmpLength)):
            count = i
            tmpLength = minLength
    return minRect, count
'''
```

and i have converted the above python code to C++ like given below:

```
void find_rot_rectangle_for_contour(vector<vector<Point> > contour,vector<RotatedRect> minRect,unsigned int count)
{

    unsigned int    minLength = 0;
    unsigned int    tmpLength = 0;
    RotatedRectangleOutput rotone;

    vector<RotatedRect> minRectone(contour.size());

    cout << "Contour size is" << contour.size() << endl;

    //minRect[0] = RotatedRect(Point2f(100, 100), Size2f(100, 50), 30);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < contour.size(); i++) 
    {
        minRectone[i] = cv::minAreaRect(contour[i]);
        minLength = MIN(minRectone[i].size.width,minRectone.size.height);
    
        if ((minLength > 500) and (minLength > tmpLength))
        {
            count = i;
            tmpLength = minLength;
        }

    }

    minRect = minRectone;
}
```

i have couple of issues here:

a) The for loop i python code runs sometimes 46,38 times depending on the  no of contours in contour list.
but in C++ code contour.size() returns 4000,so it is not matching with python code.

b) The c++ code crashes in `minLength = MIN(minRectone[i].size.width,minRectone.size.height);`
In python code we are getting w,h for minRect in the line: `minLength = min(minRect[i][1])`
how to do this similar in C++ code.

c) In the python code contours is the output of below code:

```
contours_in, _ = cv.findContours(canny_in_output_dilated, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

and in C++ code contours is the output of below code:

```
findContours(canny_in_output_dilated, contours_in, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Is it the difference in the way contours are returned differently in python and c++ or
i need to pass contour as list in C++.In python it is taken care of?

Comment: just get min x and y from all points and max x,y then you get your bbox

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my code to traverse all the contours like this:

```
void find_rot_rectangle_for_contour(vector<vector<Point> > contour, vector<RotatedRect> minRect, unsigned int count)
{

    unsigned int    minLength = 0;
    unsigned int    tmpLength = 0;
    RotatedRectangleOutput rotone;
    int loopcount = 0;

    vector<vector<Point> >::iterator itc = contour.begin();
    vector<RotatedRect> rects;

    while (itc != contour.end() && (!(*itc).empty())) {
        //Create bounding rect of object
        rects[loopcount] = minAreaRect(Mat(*itc));
        minLength = min(rects[loopcount].size.width, rects[loopcount].size.height);
        if ((minLength > 500) and (minLength > tmpLength))
        {
            count = loopcount;
            tmpLength = minLength;
        }
        loopcount++;
    }

    cout << "Count value = " << count << endl;
    cout << "LoopCount value = " << loopcount << endl;

}
```

But is is giving Assertion: Vector subscript out of range in line:

```
rects[loopcount] = minAreaRect(Mat(*itc));
```

Comment: That is because the rects is not declared and its empty. You need to set the size before you can use it. However, in your case, you dont need a vector of RotatedRect. Just just a single RotatedRect and it should fix the error